# Xcode 14.2 doesn't show properties when debug swift class with generics

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, generics

I have simple code here.

```
struct List<T> {
    class Node<T> {
        var next: Node?
        var k: T?
    }
    var head: Node<T>?
}

var list = List<Int>()
let newNode = List<Int>.Node<Int>()
newNode.k = 10
list.head = newNode
print(list)
```

I set a breakpoint at "print(list)".

When Xcode paused at the breakpoint, I want to see the head's variables in the lower-left debug window, but there was just a 'head' shown without its properties as in picture.
I have to use 'po' commands in lldb to see those values.
Am I missing something?
[image]

Comment: This is a bug in Xcode. There are many bugs related to the debugger and Swift. There's no particular answer SO can give you other than "open a Feedback; it's a bug."

Comment: @RobNapier OK, so I have to take the class outside the structure like Oleksandr said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why Xcode doesn't show you this information. But if we move class Node outside of structure List, than debugger shows us this information

```
class Node<T> {
    var next: Node?
    var k: T?
}

struct List<T> {
    var head: Node<T>?
}

var list = List<Int>()
let newNode = Node<Int>()
newNode.k = 10
list.head = newNode
print(list)
```

[image: photo of Xcode]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I do want to use this nested class Node, because I have many Nodes in my code.As Rob said above, this is an error, so the only thing I can do is to wait.

Comment: This example works correctly in Xcode 14.3.